# What happen if I only use some Statefulwidgets in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I clearly understand the difference between stateful and stateless widgets. But basically if I want, I can always use some statefulwidgets even if they will not be updated. What happen if I do that? Will there be a performance issue?

Answer (score 1):

Nothing bad.

You'll have a small overhead, and `StatelessWidget` is slightly more performant (just slightly). But overall, nothing special.